# Alineación vertical central con CSS

Tags: html, css

## Pregunta

Tengo una etiqueta div que contiene text. Quireo que el contenido de este dive se alinee verticalmente al centro. ¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

### Fragmento

```css
#box
{
  height: 180px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor.
</div>
```

## Información adicional

Pregunta inspirada en [How to vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8865458/1595451)

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8865458/1595451

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma seria usar `flex` en orientacion de columna `flex-direction: column;` de la siguiente manera:

```css
#box
{
  height: 180px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta breve

Para el caso planteado, alineación vertical del texto en un etiqueta `div`, la forma es utilizar [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display) y [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

## Fragmento

Por ejemplo, usar lo siguiente:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Al aplicar lo anterior al código incluido en la pregunta, este quedaría de la forma siguiente:

```css
#box
{
  height: 180px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor.
</div>
```

## Información adicional

Respuesta inspirada en la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8865488/1595451) a [How to vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8865458/1595451)

Comment: buenas mi respuesta te sirve? otra cosa cuando te autorespondes deberias marcar **comunidad**?

Comment: Hola. Si claro ¿y a tí que te parece mi respuesta?. En cuanto a que si debería marcar las autorespuestas como **wiki de comunidad**, eso depende, en otras palabras, no es obligatorio. Cabe mencionar que en [meta] hay una [pregunta-respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/qu%C3%A9-es-una-publicaci%C3%B3n-wiki-de-comunidad) al respecto . ¿Ya la leíste?

Comment: me parece una buena respuesta, sobre wiki de comunidad no lei, leeré ahora. disculpas que aun soy nuevo en esto de SO

Comment: No hace falta pedir disculpas. Es muy complicado leer todo y además acordarse de ello. ¡Animo!